# Minesweeper algorithm for finding neighbours?

Tags: c, algorithm

Im programming in c the minesweeper game.
im pretty at the end.
I have only problem with the last part.

in the game (see picture) when I click on the upper left field, the fields where no mine is are turned around and at the border there are numbers.

how is the algorithm for finding this field and turn them around or to show them .... I mean algorithm for the field in the green circle?

[image: MineSweeper]

Comment: I would guess it is something similar to the [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know if there is a more easier algorithm?

Comment: You'll be hard-pressed to find a simpler algorithm than [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Stack-based_recursive_implementation_.28four-way.29) to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I am doing a design from scratch, I hope it helps you.

If my game arena is nxn matrix of integers,

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I can model placing a bomb in that matrix by applying such a 3x3 matrix:

```
1 1 1
1 9 1
1 1 1
```

Here 9 denotes a bomb, you probably need to use a bigger integer. And when I say apply, I pick the location and increment it by the numbers in that 3x3 matrix. So let's place 1 bomb:

```
0 1 1 1 0
0 1 9 1 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Let's place another bomb, just next to the first one. And let's be a bit clever and not increment the location when the initial value in a cell is 9.

```
0 1 2 2 1
0 1 9 9 1
0 1 2 2 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Let's place another one this time somewhere below.

```
0 1 2 2 1
0 1 9 9 1
0 1 3 3 2
0 0 1 9 1
0 0 1 1 1
```

So if I try to start revealing numbers from bottom right. What should be my algorithm? Here is my take:

```
function revealCell(location)
{
   if(cellValueIsRevealed(location)) {
       return;
   }
   var value = revealValueOfCell(location);
   if(value > 0) 
   {
       return;
   }

   foreach(neighbor in neighbors) 
   {
       revealCell(neighbor);
   }
}
```

To implement `cellValueIsRevealed` method, one way would be to implement a matrix of booleans.

Comment: You need to add protection against infinite recursion when there are two or more adjacent zeroes.

Comment: @interjay I have added shortcut behaviour to avoid infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

**Might be a little late to answer the question, but I'll do it anyway so that if someone sees this in the future it might help them out. This is also written in C# but the general idea should be the same.**

The idea is to have a Queue of cells to visit, and a unique collection for visited cells. Start by queueing the current position and then evaluate the whole queue until it's empty. Dequeue the current cell and check if it's already visited. If it's not then check all the surrounding cells and enqueue them if they are empty cells. When you have finished the queue the hashset contains all the empty cells.

```
public void AsQueue(Queue<(int i, int j)> toVisit, HashSet<(int i, int j)> visited, Cell[] grid, int i, int j)
    {
        List<(int i, int j)> neighbours = new();
        toVisit.Enqueue((i, j));
        while (toVisit.Count != 0)
        {
            var temp = toVisit.Dequeue();
            if (!visited.Contains(temp))
            {
                Neighbours(neighbours, i, j, grid.GetLength(0), grid.GetLength(1));
                for (int k = 0; k < neighbours.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (grid[neighbours[k].i, neighbours[k].j].Type == BoxType.Empty &&
                        !(neighbours[k].i == i && neighbours[k].j == j) &&
                        !visited.Contains(neighbours[k]))
                    {
                        toVisit.Enqueue(neighbours[k]);
                    }
                }
            }
            visited.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    private void Neighbours(List<(int i, int j)> neighbours, int i, int j, int maxh, int maxw)
    {
        int[] iOffsets = new int[] { -1, 0, 1 }, jOffsets = new int[] { -1, 0, 1 };

        if (i == 0) iOffsets = new int[] { 0, 1 };
        else if (i == maxh - 1) iOffsets = new int[] { -1, 0 };

        if (j == 0) jOffsets = new int[] { 0, 1 };
        else if (j == maxw - 1) jOffsets = new int[] { -1, 0 };

        neighbours.Clear();
        foreach (var ip in iOffsets)
        {
            foreach (var jp in jOffsets)
            {
                neighbours.Add((i + ip, j + jp));
            }
        }
    }
```